# Scale gradient op in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Is there an op that:

1. When executed in a graph, outputs its input tensor as-is.
2. When building ops to compute gradients, scale the incoming gradient by the given constant

Something similar to ***tf.stop_gradient***, but instead of setting the gradient to zero, scale it by the specified constant.

If there is no such an op, what would be the easiest way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I could think of is to preprocess the gradients before applying then. You can see how to do that in the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#processing-gradients-before-applying-them).

---

Or you could do a (dirty) trick like:

```
res = ...
res = (1 - alpha) * tf.stop_gradients(res) + alpha * res
```